# counting the times a word that starts with an A or a appears from a file

Tags: python, file, design-patterns, count, matching

Ok so I have this program and its supposed to read a file, "englishsorted.txt", and count the number of times a word that begins with an "A" or "a" occurs. I'm supposed to use a pattern object. I am not really sure what I'm missing/have wrong. I appreciate the help.

```
import sys
import re

count = 0
x = open("englishsorted.txt", "r")

while 1:
    pattern = x.readline()
    if pattern == re.compile(r'^[A,a].'): #regex that finds words starting with an A or a
    count = count + 1

x.close()

print count
```

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's start with the errors you made.

- You made an infinite loop which doesn't break at the end of the file.
- You compare the pattern against the text line (which you've confusingly called `pattern`). These two are VERY different things; one is of type `str`, the other `_sre.SRE_Pattern`. Just try `'abc' == re.compile(r'^[A,a].')` to see what I'm talking about. You're supposed [to use the pattern in a search/match instead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile).

You're also reading one line at a time, while you can make the pattern search at the beginning of each line for you.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'^[A,a].*', re.MULTILINE)
```

If `re.MULTILINE` is present, the symbol `^` searches for the pattern at the beginning of the file and at the beginning of every new line. `.*` just matches the rest of the line. The dot is a wildcard symbol for one character and the star with match it for as many as there are in the line. I've added these two characters so you'll extract the whole line. If you don't care about what the lines say and just how many match your pattern, you can drop them. All in all, this should work.

```
import re

with open('englishsorted.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

pattern = re.compile(r'^[A,a].*', re.MULTILINE)
matches = re.findall(pattern, data)

print len(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first one you need to ident `count = count + 1`.
There is a better way to do this:

```
count += 1
```

Now you can't see any output just because **your program never stops**. This is caused by `while 1:`. You never put a condition that stop your cycle.

To stop it use a `break`, like here:

```
while 1:
    pattern = x.readline()

    if pattern == "":
        break

    if pattern == re.compile(r'^[A,a].'):
        count += 1
```

Please read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for more information about file reading/writing, or see below.

Then, your regex doesn't work... I've a different approach: a word starts with "A" or "a" when its first letter is one of these, so:

```
if pattern[0] == "A" or pattern[0] == "a":
    count += 1
```

I think that reading a file line by line is a little tricky as you do, so I recommend this way to that:

```
x = open("englishsorted.txt", "r")
count = 0

for line in x:
    # do something with line, in your case:
    if line[0] == "A" or line[0] == "a":
        count += 1
```

**EDIT**

Here the solution with regex:

```
import re

x = open("englishsorted.txt", "r")
count = 0

for line in x:
    if re.match("^[aA]", line):
        count += 1
```

`^` Matches the start of the string, `[aA]` indicate a set of characters, according with [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: the indentation was an unintentional mistake but for the program im required to use a regular expression pattern object so i need a regex

Comment: @AkashPatel look at the edit...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an infinite loop. The loop:

```
while 1:
   pattern = x.readline()
   ...
```

is neved ending.

You could simply write your script as follows:

```
import sys

count = 0
x = open("englishsorted.txt", "r")
exit = False

while not exit:
    pattern = x.readline()
    if not pattern:
        exit=True       
    elif pattern.startswith("A") or pattern.startswith("a"):
        count = count + 1       

x.close()

print count
```

the **exit** variable will help the script to finish the **while** loop.